# Issue with data binding on sapui5 [Same value is showed in my list.]

Tags: javascript, arrays, odata, sapui5

I have the next issue on my app made in sap web ide with sapui5 app template.

I want to show some values, the values are retrieved by a search field, everything works fine, but the issue I have is that the searched values what are shown are the same in all entries.

Here is the data shown in the app:

[image: Data showed on the app.]

On the left side, the values must be different, so I don't know why it is not working. Here are my code.

```
<mvc:View xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:sap.comp.variants="sap.ui.comp.variants" controllerName="com.my.controller.List">
<App>
    <pages>
        <Page title="{i18n>title}">
            <content>
                <List items="{path:'/PTOS_INSPSet'}" id="puntosList" growing="true" growingThreshold="10" growingScrollToLoad="false"
                    mode="SingleSelectMaster" selectionChange="onItemSelected">
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <Title text="{i18n>puntosListTitle}"/>
                            <ToolbarSpacer/>
                            <SearchField width="50%" search="onFilter"/>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <items>
                        <ObjectListItem title="{Userc1}" >
                            <firstStatus>
                                <ObjectStatus text="{IEbeln}"/>
                            </firstStatus>
                        </ObjectListItem>
                    </items>
                </List>
            </content>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
```

This in on the view.

And this is my controller for the search button.

```
onFilter: function(oEvent) {
    var aFilter = [],
    sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");
    if (sQuery && sQuery.length > 0) {
        aFilter.push(new Filter("IEbeln", FilterOperator.Contains , sQuery));

    }
    var oList = this.getView().byId("puntosList");
    var oBinding = oList.getBinding("items");
    oBinding.filter(aFilter);
}
```

All of this is retrieved from a private odata service declared on my manifest.

**UPDATE**

I checked on my back end service, and i set two parameters as keys instead of one and that fixed my issue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you check if the keys for the returned ODATA response are unique for each entry ? This may happen if the key values are not unique in your ODATA entityset

Comment: i have one key, for example IEbeln is the key in this case, but that key has some asociated values from Userc1, example:

iebeln -> userc1[a], userc1[b], userc1[c]...

Comment: You code does not seem to have any problem(works with the Northwind service). I presume it can only be because of your private odata service. Check the response in the odata after applying the filter. You may also increase the keys. Also check SAPUI5 Diagnostics(Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) & check the Control Tree for correct bindings applied on all the ObjectListItems

Comment: OK, i checked on my back end code, and i set two parameters as keys and that resolved my issue, thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code does not seem to have any problem(works with the Northwind service). It can be because of your private odata service. Check the response in the OData after applying the filter. You may also increase the number of keys in the OData entity set. Also check SAPUI5 Diagnostics(Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) & check the Control Tree for correct bindings applied on all the ObjectListItems.

Edit: Based on you comment, this problem was solved by adding another key.

Answer (score 0):

Are you binding your list directly by back end ?

Comment: Yes, directly from my backend.

Comment: After binding filter it will call back end. so check your back end code. If back end code is OK then increase not of keys in entity set.